# Is there any point in returning IEnumerable from iterator methods in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iterator, ienumerable

Is there any point in returning an `IEnumerable` in a Controller's action, when that `IEnumerable` came from an iterator method?

From what I know - they will be fully buffered, i.e a call to `.ToList()` is most likely being done, or `.ToArray()` under the hood.

*Bonus: Could someone link me the code responsible for that in ASP.NET Core?*

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-5.0) might be worth reading. Quote: _ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later buffers the result of the following action before providing it to the serializer_

Comment: They won't be fully buffered, and `ToList()` isn't called. The actual response is generated by the runtime *OR* the specific `ActionResult` implementation which could easily iterate over the results to write directly to the output stream. Or it could enumerate over the results to save RAM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you toss a link to where this is happening? I'm curious to see how this specific buffering is implemented - both for `IEnumerable`, and `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: I tested JSON.NET (see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s27zFn)) and System.Text.Json ([here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyS3DO)) and found that, while JSON.NET will stream the result, System.Text.Json doesn't currently. From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1570) it looks like System.Text.Json will support it in .NET 6 ([follow-up in .NET 6 thread](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6098#issuecomment-824935517)). My suggested test methodology wasn't so ridiculous after all, was it?